# Pandas converting datetimes objects to timestamps or integers when subbing in data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a data frame that I need to update with additional data. To do this I first initialise and join on an empty data frame with the correct number of rows. However odd things are happening with the object classes when I overwrite the empty columns with datetime objects. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

# empty data frame
df1 = post_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'var':[np.nan]*int(10),
    'date':[np.nan]*int(10)
    })
# full data frame
df2 = post_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'var':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    'date':['2020-01-01']*int(10)
    })

# make df2.date datetime
convert_date = [datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%Y-%m-%d') for dt_str in df2.date]
# NOTE 1: Notice that before subbing into pandas dataframe 
# the class is datetime.datetime 
print(type(convert_date[0]))
df2.loc[:,'date'] = convert_date
# NOTE 2: But after replacing the column the class is 
# pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
print(type(df2.date[0]))

# join dataframes together
df_join = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index(drop=True)
# NOTE 3: Now the np.nan is converted to NaT (this is fine) and the data is 
# still pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
print(type(df_join.date[0]))
print(type(df_join.loc[len(df_join)-1,'date']))

# make data to sub into the data frame
data_sub = [datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%d/%m/%Y') for dt_str in ['01/01/2019']*10]
# NOTE 4: The data_sub class is datetime.datetime
print(type(data_sub[0]))

# Sub data into data frame
df_join.loc[0:9, 'date'] = data_sub
# NOTE 5: The data that has been subbed into the data frame is still datetime.datetime 
# (pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp like before?) but the timestamps from before
# have been convereted into integers?
print(type(df_join.date[0]))
print(type(df_join.loc[len(df_join)-1,'date']))

# print the data frame
print(df_join)
```

**Script output:**

```
# NOTE 1:
<class 'datetime.datetime'>

# NOTE 2:
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

# NOTE 3:
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType'>
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

# NOTE 4:
<class 'datetime.datetime'>

# NOTE 5:
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
<class 'int'>

# Final data frame
    var                 date
0   NaN  2019-01-01 00:00:00
1   NaN  2019-01-01 00:00:00
2   NaN  2019-01-01 00:00:00
3   NaN  2019-01-01 00:00:00
4   NaN  2019-01-01 00:00:00
5   NaN  2019-01-01 00:00:00
6   NaN  2019-01-01 00:00:00
7   NaN  2019-01-01 00:00:00
8   NaN  2019-01-01 00:00:00
9   NaN  2019-01-01 00:00:00
10  0.0  1577836800000000000
11  1.0  1577836800000000000
12  2.0  1577836800000000000
13  3.0  1577836800000000000
14  4.0  1577836800000000000
15  5.0  1577836800000000000
16  6.0  1577836800000000000
17  7.0  1577836800000000000
18  8.0  1577836800000000000
19  9.0  1577836800000000000
```

Why are the data classes being converted in some cases but not others and how can I ensure the dataframe date column remains `datetime.datetime` class?

Comment: Pandas has its own pd.Timestamp object that works better than datetime.datetime.  I recommend using pd.to_datetime with your list of string times.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, this resolved the issue.